# Cloud Functions deployment requirements.txt failing

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have a function which uses pandas and google cloud storage.
My requirements.txt looks like this:

```
pandas>=1.5.0
google-cloud-storeage>=1.36.0
```

And I am getting the following error:

> Build failed: Collecting pandas>=1.2.2 Downloading
> pandas-1.5.2-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
> (12.2 MB) ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 12.2/12.2 MB 50.3
> MB/s eta 0:00:00 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the
> requirement google-cloud-storeage>=1.36.0 (from versions: none) ERROR:
> No matching distribution found for google-cloud-storeage>=1.36.0;
> Error ID: 0ea8a540

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: which python version are you using?

Comment: `google-cloud-storage` not `google-cloud-storeage`

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to replicate your error and found out that there's a typographical error or misspelled `google-cloud-storeage`.

See below sample screenshot:

[image: screenshot].

See the sample code below:

```
pandas>=1.5.0
google-cloud-storage>=1.36.0
```

Also, keep in mind that installing pandas can only work with the following versions of Python: 3.8, 3.9, 3.10, and 3.11.

For more information, check this public documentation about [Specifying dependencies in Python](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/specifying-dependencies-python) in the `requirements.txt` file and `requirements.txt` file format, see the [pip documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#requirements-files:%7E:text=in%20pip%E2%80%99s%20requests.-,Requirements%20Files,-%23).